# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hook')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, tooltip, antd

[TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hook')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLxih.png)

I am working on a Nextjs application but getting this error with antd library. I'm using the modal component and tooltip component which causes a re-render on open and close and spits out this error multiple times. Same goes for the tooltip when I mouse over it. Has anyone experienced this? and how did you fix it?. Answers appreciated!

import { Button, Modal, Tooltip } from 'antd';

`const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);`

```
<div className="d-flex gap-2">
  <Tooltip title="Edit">
    <EditOutlined className="h5 pointer text-warning" />
  </Tooltip>
  <Tooltip title="Publish">
    <CheckOutlined className="h5 pointer text-success ml-2" />
  </Tooltip>
</div>

<Button
   className="w-100"
   onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}
   type="primary"
   shape="round"
   size="large"
   icon={<UploadOutlined />}
>
 Open modal
</Button>

<Modal
   title="Modal title"
   centered
   open={isModalOpen}
   onCancel={() => setIsModalOpen(false)}
   footer={null}
>
  <p>Some contents...</p>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using codesandbox

Comment: It was React Dev Tools plugin for me

Answer (score 6):

in my case I have got that below error, when I'm using React DevTools Chrome extension. after removing that extension error are fixed

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue using a Next 13 app router application. React Dev Tools throw this error non stop on the console.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Screenshot]

I had the same error when using antd file upload.
But it was introduced by one of the Chrome extensions, not antd.
Refreshing the Chrome extension will remove this error.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this happening recently with the react-context-devtool chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-context-devtool/oddhnidmicpefilikhgeagedibnefkcf

Removing it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

This caused because of one of the extensions for me, I disabled the chrome extensions and it no longer appeared

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).